# How do I add sequential values to a pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append

I have a data frame like the following:

| AF | Important Info |
| --- | --- |
| Trial One |  |
| Trial Two |  |

There is an entirely blank column, and it needs to be populated with data. I will have a near final data frame like the following:

| AF | Important Info |
| --- | --- |
| Trial One | '70' |
| Trial Two | '88' |

How would I go about adding additional values to the "Important Info" column, such that the result is like this:

| AF | Important Info |
| --- | --- |
| Trial One | '70', '99' |
| Trial Two | '88', '71' |

Thank you!

Comment: If you insist on using this format, how do you expect `Important Info` to be stored? As a string, or as a list?

Answer (score 0):

I would consider storing your data in long format like:

```
          AF Info
0  Trial One   70
1  Trial One   99
2  Trial Two   88
3  Trial Two   71
```

Then if you really want to see that info on one line, you can do:

```
>>> df.groupby('AF').agg(list)
               Info
AF
Trial One  [70, 99]
Trial Two  [88, 71]

# OR

>>> df.astype(str).groupby('AF').agg(', '.join)
             Info
AF
Trial One  70, 99
Trial Two  88, 71
```

And, this still allows you to perform other calculations per group...

```
>>> df.groupby('AF').mean()
           Info
AF
Trial One  84.5
Trial Two  79.5
```